# 403 errors from load balancer while new instances are booting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, passenger, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a RoR app running on elastic beanstalk.  I have occasionally seen 403 errors from Passenger for a while.  Most of the time 1 server is running but this gets increased to 3 or 4 instances in busy periods during the day.

Session stickeyness is not turned on

I have noticed that when a new server is started the ELB is sending requests to it before bundle install has finished.

If I ssh to the newly started server I can see in /var/app/current/ that the app has not yet been installed and if I run top it looks like bundler is running and compiling things with cc1, etc.
/var/app/support/log/passenger.log shows that requests to valid urls within my rails app are being received and responded to with 404.  Hardly surprising because the app isn't there yet

After 5-10 minutes all of the compiling is complete and the app files appear in /var/app/current and all is well.

This doesn't seem quite right to me.  How do I set up the ELB / my rails app so that the ELB can tell when it is ready to receive requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to this.  There was no application health check url set.  In this case the ELB pings the instance to see if it's healthy, i.e. it checks that it is booted rather than if rails is up and running.  Setting the health check url to '/login/' fixed it for me because this gives a 404 until rails in running and a 200 afterwards.

Elastic beanstalk demands 2 correct responses before it deems an instance to be healthy.  It checks the instance every 5 minutes.  This means that an instance can take a while to start serving requests.  i.e. it takes boot time + waiting for next poll from elb + 5 minutes before it sees any real traffic